# Why Discord site isn't loaded with Puppeteer Node.js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
await page.goto('https://discord.com/channels/850682587273625661/919026857926590535', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0 });
await page.screenshot({ path: 'discor.png' })
```

The main idea here is that if I puppeteer.launch() site is loaded whereas I use puppeteer.connect() is looks as if Discord block my script. Are there any ways to bypass this restriction of Discord?

Answer (score 0):

This url redirects you to a login page, you'd then have to actually log in as you would do manually:

```js
await page.goto('https://discord.com/channels/850682587273625661/919026857926590535');

// enter email
const emailtarget = await page.waitForSelector("input[name=email]", {visible: true});
await emailtarget.type("my@email.com");

// enter password
const passtarget = await page.waitForSelector("input[name=password]", {visible: true});
await passtarget.type("mySecretPass");

// submit
const submitBtn = await page.waitForSelector("button[type=submit]", {visible: true});
await submitBtn.click();

// wait for redirection
await page.waitForNavigation();

// should be logged in, take screenshot
await page.screenshot({ path: 'discor.png' });
```